# Could not load file or assembly System.Collections, Version=4.0.11.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a weird issue in the DotNet Framework 4.7.2 WebApi.

Error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
> HResult=0x80070002
> Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> Source=Microsoft.Web.Administration

[image]

Recently, I had upgraded my webapi from 4.6 to 4.7.2 dotnet framework. The older version is working fine. I am getting this error on 4.7.2.

I noticed that when I run my Webapi on 4.6 version, I can see the following DLLs in the bin folder. However, when I run the same WebAPI on 4.7.2 version, I can not see DLLs in the bin folder.

- System.Collections
- System.Collections.NonGeneric
- System.Collections.Specialized
- System.Collections.Concurrent

I also got the same post on StackOverflow but there is no answer.

URL: [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734636/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-collections-version-4-0-0-0)

Comment: For these namespace "System.Collections" ... you shouldn't have any DLL in the output folder, unless you added the Nuget Package manually. But there is no need for a .NET Framework 4.7.2, at least for system related libraries.

Comment: Likely you have weird nuget issue where you targeted thr wrong library or changed something. Consider reloading all your nugets, potentially clean then build

Comment: @TheGeneral I did all these things. I have added an image of my error. Server Manager is using "Microsoft.Web.Administration" namespace and this namespace using "system.collection" internally